# Exchange 2007 iOS 6.1 protection

Tags: logging, exchange-2007, iphone

In case you hadn't heard there is a 6.1 bug that will be causing us headaches
http://www.zdnet.com/ios-6-1-banned-from-corporate-servers-due-to-exchange-snafu-7000011064/

I have seen an article on how you can block exchange 2010+ from allowing syncing with 6.1 devices but it doesn't cover Exchange 2007
http://exchangeserverpro.com/block-ios-61-exchange-2010

What logs do I need to limit and how can I do it via the EMC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.zdnet.com/apple-releases-ios-6-1-2-fixes-exchange-bug-lock-screen-bug-still-open-7000011510/

Supposed fix is 6.1.2...we'll see.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, this issue affects Exchange *transaction logs*. You absolutely should not 'limit' these logs in any way.

Transaction logs are committed to the exchange database and flushed after an *exchange-aware* backup. If you notice transaction logs growing, you have two options - move the logs to a drive that's big enough to hold a typical day's log growth under these circumstances (I'm assuming you carry out a daily exchange backup there) or increase the frequency of the backups.

I'm still looking into ways of dealing with the problem on Exchange 2007 myself, but the issue needs to be fixed by addressing the devices causing the problem rather than limiting the database files on the server

Depending on how your firewall works, you may be able to block access requests from 6.1 devices based on user-agent string (think it's `Apple-iPhone3C1/1002.144` for 6.1 devices)

Comment: That would make sense why I haven't see a quick fix for limiting the logging.